# How to update installed plugins in eclipse via command line?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have installed a feature group in eclipse, i used the installUI to do this. 
This worked fine for the first time. Now if the plugin in that feature group has been updated/modified or if a plugin is added then the changes is not reflected if i run the same installIU command again! Using the UI in eclipse however works!! 
Any idea how to achieve this through command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible to update using the P2 director. If you want to update your feature, you would have to first uninstall it, then install it again, but this time intalling the latest version.

Example, Installing:

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash 
-repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno 
-installIUs org.eclipse.egit.feature.group,org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group,
org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group,org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
```

Example, uninstalling:

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -nosplash 
-uninstallIU org.eclipse.egit.feature.group,org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group,
org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group,org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
```

An example of WHY p2 will not update via command line is listed below:

> Installation vs Update: Although only an isssue when using the
>   lower-level p2 Core APIs, specifying an IU to install (as a root IU)
>   does not automatically update any existing versions of that IU.
>   Although the p2 planner will consider replacing a non-root IU to
>   satisfy a dependency, p2 will never update a root IU. Updating a root
>   IU requires explicitly uninstalling the old IU and installing the new
>   version. Note that the p2 Install New Software / Update Software
>   wizard does detect this situation and transforms installations into
>   updates.

References: [Eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/291253/), [Vogella blog](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/04/04/installing-eclipse-features-via-the-command-line-with-the-p2-director/), [Paul Websters blog](http://pweclipse.blogspot.de/2012/02/p2-can-update-your-eclipseini.html), [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html), [Equinox/p2/FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/FAQ#Using_p2_for_Updating)